# From row to column vector for a specific condition in Python

Tags: python, numpy

The code selects the positive values in the matrix and gives the corresponding indices. However, I would like the output of positive values in a column vector instead of a row. The current and desired outputs are attached.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan
import math
Flux=np.array([[-1, 2, 0],[4,-7,8],[1,-9,3]])

values = Flux[Flux >= 0]
print("positive values =",[values])

indices = np.array(np.where(Flux >= 0)).T
print("indices =",[indices])
```

The current output is

```
positive values = [array([2, 0, 4, 8, 1, 3])]
indices = [array([[0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 2]], dtype=int64)]
```

The desired output is

```
positive values = [array([[2], [0], [4], [8], [1], [3]])]
indices = [array([[0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 2]], dtype=int64)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can add an extra dimension when slicing your array:

```
values = Flux[Flux>=0,None]
```

output:

```
array([[2],
       [0],
       [4],
       [8],
       [1],
       [3]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
values = [[x] for x in values]
```

and make it a numpy array like this:

```
values = Flux[Flux >= 0]
values = np.array([[x] for x in values])
print("positive values =",[values])
```